# kubeadm init error: kubeadm timed out waiting for the condition

Tags: docker, ubuntu, kubernetes, kubeadm

I try execute

```
kubeadm init --apiserver-advertise-address 49.232.211.230 --pod-network-cidr=10.244.0.0/16 -v=9
```

print log:

```
[wait-control-plane] Waiting for the kubelet to boot up the control plane as static Pods from directory "/etc/kubernetes/manifests". This can take up to 4m0s
I0426 01:21:19.624413   30483 round_trippers.go:435] curl -k -v -XGET  -H "Accept: application/json, */*" -H "User-Agent: kubeadm/v1.21.0 (linux/amd64) kubernetes/cb303e6" 'https://49.232.211.230:6443/healthz?timeout=10s'
I0426 01:21:19.626723   30483 round_trippers.go:454] GET https://49.232.211.230:6443/healthz?timeout=10s  in 0 milliseconds
I0426 01:21:19.626800   30483 round_trippers.go:460] Response Headers:
I0426 01:21:20.127086   30483 round_trippers.go:435] curl -k -v -XGET  -H "User-Agent: kubeadm/v1.21.0 (linux/amd64) kubernetes/cb303e6" -H "Accept: application/json, */*" 'https://49.232.211.230:6443/healthz?timeout=10s'
I0426 01:21:20.127764   30483 round_trippers.go:454] GET https://49.232.211.230:6443/healthz?timeout=10s  in 0 milliseconds
I0426 01:21:20.127782   30483 round_trippers.go:460] Response Headers:
I0426 01:21:20.627098   30483 round_trippers.go:435] curl -k -v -XGET  -H "Accept: application/json, */*" -H "User-Agent: kubeadm/v1.21.0 (linux/amd64) kubernetes/cb303e6" 'https://49.232.211.230:6443/healthz?timeout=10s'
I0426 01:21:20.627747   30483 round_trippers.go:454] GET https://49.232.211.230:6443/healthz?timeout=10s  in 0 milliseconds
```

finally:

```
    Unfortunately, an error has occurred:
        timed out waiting for the condition

    This error is likely caused by:
        - The kubelet is not running
        - The kubelet is unhealthy due to a misconfiguration of the node in some way (required cgroups disabled)

    If you are on a systemd-powered system, you can try to troubleshoot the error with the following commands:
        - 'systemctl status kubelet'
        - 'journalctl -xeu kubelet'

    Additionally, a control plane component may have crashed or exited when started by the container runtime.
    To troubleshoot, list all containers using your preferred container runtimes CLI.

    Here is one example how you may list all Kubernetes containers running in docker:
        - 'docker ps -a | grep kube | grep -v pause'
        Once you have found the failing container, you can inspect its logs with:
        - 'docker logs CONTAINERID'

couldn't initialize a Kubernetes cluster
k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kubeadm/app/cmd/phases/init.runWaitControlPlanePhase
    /workspace/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/_output/dockerized/go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kubeadm/app/cmd/phases/init/waitcontrolplane.go:114
k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kubeadm/app/cmd/phases/workflow.(*Runner).Run.func1
    /workspace/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/_output/dockerized/go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kubeadm/app/cmd/phases/workflow/runner.go:234
k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kubeadm/app/cmd/phases/workflow.(*Runner).visitAll
    /workspace/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/_output/dockerized/go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kubeadm/app/cmd/phases/workflow/runner.go:421
k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kubeadm/app/cmd/phases/workflow.(*Runner).Run
    /workspace/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/_output/dockerized/go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kubeadm/app/cmd/phases/workflow/runner.go:207
k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kubeadm/app/cmd.newCmdInit.func1
    /workspace/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/_output/dockerized/go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kubeadm/app/cmd/init.go:152
k8s.io/kubernetes/vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).execute
    /workspace/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/_output/dockerized/go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra/command.go:850
k8s.io/kubernetes/vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).ExecuteC
    /workspace/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/_output/dockerized/go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra/command.go:958
k8s.io/kubernetes/vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).Execute
    /workspace/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/_output/dockerized/go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra/command.go:895
k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kubeadm/app.Run
    /workspace/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/_output/dockerized/go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kubeadm/app/kubeadm.go:50
main.main
    _output/dockerized/go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kubeadm/kubeadm.go:25
runtime.main
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/proc.go:225
runtime.goexit
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:1371
error execution phase wait-control-plane
k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kubeadm/app/cmd/phases/workflow.(*Runner).Run.func1
    /workspace/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/_output/dockerized/go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kubeadm/app/cmd/phases/workflow/runner.go:235
k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kubeadm/app/cmd/phases/workflow.(*Runner).visitAll
    /workspace/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/_output/dockerized/go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kubeadm/app/cmd/phases/workflow/runner.go:421
k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kubeadm/app/cmd/phases/workflow.(*Runner).Run
    /workspace/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/_output/dockerized/go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kubeadm/app/cmd/phases/workflow/runner.go:207
k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kubeadm/app/cmd.newCmdInit.func1
    /workspace/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/_output/dockerized/go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kubeadm/app/cmd/init.go:152
k8s.io/kubernetes/vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).execute
    /workspace/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/_output/dockerized/go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra/command.go:850
k8s.io/kubernetes/vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).ExecuteC
    /workspace/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/_output/dockerized/go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra/command.go:958
k8s.io/kubernetes/vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).Execute
    /workspace/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/_output/dockerized/go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra/command.go:895
k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kubeadm/app.Run
    /workspace/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/_output/dockerized/go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kubeadm/app/kubeadm.go:50
main.main
    _output/dockerized/go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kubeadm/kubeadm.go:25
runtime.main
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/proc.go:225
runtime.goexit
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:1371
```

Configuration file after execution failure:
"/var/lib/kubelet/config.yaml" 38L, 921C

```
apiVersion: kubelet.config.k8s.io/v1beta1
authentication:
  anonymous:
    enabled: false
  webhook:
    cacheTTL: 0s
    enabled: true
  x509:
    clientCAFile: /etc/kubernetes/pki/ca.crt
authorization:
  mode: Webhook
  webhook:
    cacheAuthorizedTTL: 0s
    cacheUnauthorizedTTL: 0s
cgroupDriver: systemd
clusterDNS:
- 10.96.0.10
clusterDomain: cluster.local
cpuManagerReconcilePeriod: 0s
evictionPressureTransitionPeriod: 0s
fileCheckFrequency: 0s
healthzBindAddress: 127.0.0.1
healthzPort: 10248
httpCheckFrequency: 0s
imageMinimumGCAge: 0s
kind: KubeletConfiguration
logging: {}
nodeStatusReportFrequency: 0s
nodeStatusUpdateFrequency: 0s
resolvConf: /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf
rotateCertificates: true
runtimeRequestTimeout: 0s
shutdownGracePeriod: 0s
shutdownGracePeriodCriticalPods: 0s
staticPodPath: /etc/kubernetes/manifests
streamingConnectionIdleTimeout: 0s
syncFrequency: 0s
volumeStatsAggPeriod: 0s
```

I even reinstalled the system,But it's still like this.

I tried all the kubeadm methods in the kubernetes documentation.

It's always been like this, I can't help it.

Thanks, please help me.

Comment: I solved my problem from herehttps://github.com/kubernetes/kubeadm/issues/1390#issuecomment-539982626

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As it's mentioned in the kubeadm init  command logs it's a kubelet server issue or CRI issue, Rest your cluster using the kubeadm reset -f command  and Try to perform these steps in order:

1. Stop Kubelet and CRI services :

```
sudo systemctl stop kubelet
sudo systemctl stop docker (if you are using docker)
```

2. flush iptables and turn swapoff (Important if any firewall service is running verify that [kubernetes_cluster_ports](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/install-kubeadm/) enabled) :

```
sudo iptables -F && sudo iptables -t nat -F && sudo iptables -t mangle -F && sudo iptables -X
sudo swapoff -a
```

3. start CRI and  kubelet service and verify that it's working fine (in activating status):

```
    sudo systemctl start --now docker
    sudo systemctl start --now kubelet
    sudo systemctl status kubelet
```

4. initialize your cluster

```
    sudo kubeadm init
```

If all these steps are done and you still got the issue verify your networking configuration propably docker could not initialize a specific pod for the control plane due to a network issue.

Comment: Thanks for your answer,but i execute 
```kubeadm init```
is normal. add ```--apiserver-advertise-address=49.232.211.230```,It's still the same.
I don’t know why I can’t connect to my host ip,I am sure my port is open.

Comment: actually the --apiserver-advertise-address is optional if you are running the command in the target VM itself, try to add  Domain name to your machine  in /etc/hosts <ip_address> <domain_name> ( hostname <domain_name>) and add this option to your kubeadm init command : --control-plane-endpoint=<domain_name>  
now the api-server will be reached with it's domain name.
( Based on the kubeadm docs this option is recommended Link below  : https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/create-cluster-kubeadm/ )

Comment: Thank you again for your reply.But I seem to know why.This kubernetes cluster is built by me on the cloud provider,But there are two different cloud providers,So I want to establish via public IP.I see the reason here https://github.com/kubernetes/kubeadm/issues/1390